# IBM Cognos Report Studio: Is it possible to make one of the drill-through definitions standard?

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-10

I have an element in one of my reports with multiple drill-through definitions in the collection. This is fine, however, I want to make one of these definitions the standard one, so that when the user left-clicks the element, this definition will be chosen (i.e. I don't want to prompt the user for which definition he/she wants to use).

This way, the user can choose between the drill-throughs in the collection by "right-click -> Go To".

Anyone knows any way of doing this? Haven't found any indications that this is possible from what I've read so far, and from the drill-through options available in cognos.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: You can run any report (including parameters) via a URL. So you could dynamically build the correct drill through URL, unlock the cell and put it in there as a seperate link/icon. If you want to get really funky you can try overriding the existing left click functionality using Javascript but this won't work in PDF. So if you want this to work in anything besides HTML you'll need a seperate link.

Comment: Thanks for the input, Nick! Although it isn't what I originally was looking for, it might actually work. However, it will need some more maintenance.